# Limit possible values for ForeignKey to a subset of models

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have the following model:

```
class SOA(models.Model):
    adviser = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

The `adviser` can not be any user, but a user which satisfies certain requirements (for example, a user which belongs to a certain group). This is relevant for example when dealing with forms: a dropdown to select the `adviser` shows me all users in the system, but I want to filter that and only show users which are actually advisers (which is defined, in this case, by belonging to an `advisers` group)

Is it possible to handle this kind of constraint at the model level? Or maybe when populating the select box in the form?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [`limit_choices_to`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) init argument of `ForeignKey` class. For example:

```py
adviser = models.ForeignKey(User, limit_choices_to={"is_staff": True})
```

For more complex queries, you can use [`Q` objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Q):

```
..., limit_choices_to=Q(share_holder=True) | Q(distributor=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you have an example of use with a model `@property`?

Comment: I ended up modifying the field queryset in the form, which seems more flexible